# Energy when the speed of light is infinite

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, mass-energy

Assuming that the speed of light was infinite, we would get back to Newtonian physics and special relativity wouldn't be as relevant anymore.

However, this would mean that the energy is infinite as well since E=mc^2+..., meaning that even the smallest amount of mass could even turn into infinite energy.

What is an explanation to this infinite energy?

Comment: The derivation for $E=mc^2$ builds on the assumption that $c$ is finite.

Comment: "assuming the speed of light is infinite" is a question of what-if type listed in the [types of questions you shouldn't ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you want to know how to go back to Newtonian mechanics from special relativity, the proper limit is to assume that $v$ is much smaller than $c$, not that $c$ is infinite. There can be no physical explanation for the "infinite energy" you get for infinite speed of light because *physically, the speed of light is finite*, so it's not clear what you're looking for here.

Comment: I think it is a very legitimate question. There are always cases in physics in which yo can take known constants to zero or infinity in order to see what happens. Another example would be taking Planck's constant to zero in the path integral to receive classical mechanics from quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, the correct formula is

$$E^2-p^2c^2=m^2c^4$$

or, solved for $E$,

$$E=\sqrt{m^2c^4+p^2c^2}=mc^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}=\gamma mc^2$$

If you Taylor expand $\gamma$ in powers of $v^2/c^2$, you will get

$$E=mc^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{3}{8}mv^2\frac{v^2}{c^2}+\frac{5}{16}mv^2\frac{v^4}{c^4}+\mathcal{O}(v^6/c^6)$$

You see that in the limit of large $c$ only the first two terms survive since $v^2/c^2$ becomes very small. The second term is the well known kinetic energy. The first term is a fixed constant which is actually indeed infinite. However, you might have already heard that energy, as well as potential, is only defined up to an additive constant. Therefore, it is possible to shift the energy scale such that the constant first term vanishes:

$$E'=E-mc^2=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\mathcal{O}(v^2/c^2)$$

This is what we have in non-relativistic mechanics.

Comment: Yes you're completely right about the energy. I should've written E=mc^2+...

Comment: But is there a more physical explanation to infinite energy rather than it just being like reference energy?

Comment: To be honest, I have no better explanation. But I need to note that this is not unusual in physics. Already in classical electromagnetism one cannot define the electric potential of a point charge such that it is finite (or even zero) at the origin: $\Phi(r)=\tfrac{q}{r} + C$ is such that no matter how you select C you will get an infinity at $r=0$. So you leave it and live with an infinity at $r=0$ defining the potential such that it is zero at $r=\infty$. 

Similar infinities frequently emerge in quantum field theories (see e.g. zero point energy).

Comment: It's not c that is infinite, the real problem has been that calculations of m in QFT led to infinite mass. That was fixed with renormalizarion

Comment: And the real physical reasons is that if the particleninteracts trru an infinite number of Feynman diagrams it's infinite unless most of them cancel out. Renormalization found a way to do it.

Comment: @BobBee: Isn't it a valid thing to explore how special relativity behaves in the non-relativistic limit? Of course we have better theories of matter than point particles in some space-time but we can still use SR as a model and explore its properties.

Comment: Yes. Valid. But usually done by taking v/c ----> 0, or v small enough. When you start plugging in infinities it's easy to mix things up. The problem with the previous argument that you can take a constant infinity and just make it as though zero fails when you go to general relativity where any mass causes curvature and infinite mass can't be set to zero

Comment: @BobBee: Well, mass is not what we want to set to zero but a constant term in the energy. So, actually, one would need to look at the energy momentum tensor of a point particle and see how it behaves in this limit... A point particle has a delta-like density distribution already, so the $(00)$ component of the energy momentum tensor is ugly by construction, question is now what happens if we try to take the non-relativistic limit (which way ever we would want to do it)...

Comment: No, that's a bigger issue. Masses of point particles that on some way take general relativity (GR) into account will have to wait for a quantum gravity theory. I was talking more classical in the sense that a constant term in the energy, if c is infinity is infinity, and that has gravitational implications with infinite curvature. You can't just ignore it like you could if a constant term in QFT. If c is infinity my guess is both SR and GR go away, and you have Galilean space and time separately, electromagnetism also does not work (Maxwell eq has c), and all you have is 1840's physics. More

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57511/discussion-between-bob-bee-and-photon).

Comment: Worse, if c is infinity causality is instantaneous, everything that happens in the universe now affects you now, etc. I forget how Mr Tompkins in Wonderland treats it but it's probably much worse than his great stories. If c is infinite probably there is no E = m$c^2$ equation.

Comment: Ps. A mistake on continuing on chat, my iPad did something to click on it. Let us get it settled here

Comment: Actually, no need to continue. The answer is wrong on my arguments but you and everyone can use it if you ignore SR, GR, and electromagnetism